# Not able to print clicked line in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using QTextBrowser for printing data but want to check which line is clicked and get its string. I looked at other resources and was able to make this, but its not printing the line.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class TextBrowser(QtWidgets.QTextBrowser):

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            tc = self.cursorForPosition(event.pos())
            print("text = ", tc.block().text())
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(104, 105)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget") 
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_8")
        self.code_textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.code_textBrowser, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.code_textBrowser.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.code_textBrowser.append("ab\ncde\nfghi\njklmn\nopqrstu")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = TextBrowser()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)    
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons why I do not recommend modifying the code generated by .ui is that it causes confusion so for my possible solution you must restore that file (run pyuic again) and call the generated file as gui.py.

The problem is that the cursorForPosition returns the cursor associated with "TextBrowser" (in your case "ui") and not with "code_textBrowser", that a class inherits from class T does not imply that all attributes are of the same class T they will be the same.

The solution is to implement the logic in another class that inherits from a QObject like QMainWindow and implement the logic using code_textBrowser.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from gui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.code_textBrowser.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (
            obj is self.ui.code_textBrowser.viewport()
            and event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress
        ):
            tc = self.ui.code_textBrowser.cursorForPosition(event.pos())
            print("text = ", tc.block().text())

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```